# Why doesn't the JDK Collections.distinct enforce that the parameters contain the same element type?

Tags: java, types

The method's [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#disjoint%28java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Collection%29).

I would expect that the following code resulted in a type error:

```
List<String> ls = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> li = new ArrayList<>();
boolean result = Collections.disjoint(ls, li);
```

Yet it does not and will always return true.
Why would it allow this?

Comment: Well, it makes sense... a `List<String>` will always be disjoint to `List<Integer>`. Why would you want a type error?

Comment: The types are erased at runtime anyway.

Comment: Even if they both contain `null` values?

Comment: It's defined with a wildcard generic for the two parameters meaning they can both be different types.  If it were defined like the `addAll` method with a common type then it would result in a compile error.

Comment: @kajacx Oops, didn't take that into consideration. Too late to edit though...

Comment: After sleeping on this, my guess is that Sun was attempting to not break old code when generics were added. 
I'm not sure how this could have broken old code, though.

Other languages that were generic from the start, such as Scala, require the type to be the same on methods like contains, sameElements, etc.

http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.1/index.html#scala.collection.Set@contains(elem:A):Boolean

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything strange in this. Think about the fact that equality in Java is expressed between objects, you have `boolean equals(Object other)` not `boolean equals(T other)`.

Since `equals` is indeed used to find if two collections are disjoint (or `hashCode()` in case of sets) why would you require to raise a type error?

According to this point of view even

```
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
boolean test = set.contains("foobar");
```

should be considered an error.

Comment: Why shouldn't that be considered an error? That should be a compile error, in my opinion.

Comment: @BrendenBrown: Why should it be a compile error? There is a precise rationale behind this choice, since there is no point in preventing at compile time to check if an object is contained in a collection, even if it's not of the same generics type. That's the same rationale between `remove(Object o)`. There is no harmful side effect. Parametric polymorphism is made to make code safe, not to limit the developer. Forbidding to use `contains` with a different type doesn't break type safety, differently from, for example, `add(E object)` which indeed is typed.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the exact reasoning behind the decision. However, it allows some very useful behavior, such as comparing the a set of `Foo` and a set of `Bar extends Foo` for disjointness.  The wildcard types are the way to allow this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a better question: Why would it?

Consider `Foo extends Bar`, `Bar extends Jo`, `Blo extends Jo` and then:

```
List<Jo> jos = new ArrayList<Jo>();
List<Bar> bars = new ArrayList<Bar>();

//populate both lists arbitrarily

Collections.disjoint(jos, bars);
```

The above call is perfectly valid and could return `true` or `false`, why block this?

Comment: I think it is invalid because the programmer probably never needed to do that and the result is always the same.

Comment: I updated my answer slightly (the comment in the code).  You say `the programmer probably never needed to do that`, that seems presumptuous?  The lists could contain entirely the same instances or not even the same classes.  By trying to enforce same-type collections in situations such as above, java would limit an otherwise useful, valid scenario.